# Antialiasing a PPM file

Tags: c++, image-processing, antialiasing, edges, ppm

I got this output from the code below [circle.ppm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLVs.png) and it has a lot of jaggy edges. I need some type of antialiasing method I believe, but I have trouble getting started.

What would be the simplest way of getting rid of them?

```
//******************** INCLUDE: ********************

#include <fstream>                      // ofstream
#include <iostream>                     // cin, cout
#include <cmath>                        // sqrt, pow

using namespace std;                    // USING STANDARD NAMESPACE

//******************** DECLARATION OF FUNCTIONS: ********************

bool isInsideCircle(int x,int y);       // CHECKS IF (X,Y) IS INSIDE CIRCLE
int Brightness(int x,int y);            // DISTANCE FROM CENTER


//******************** VARIABLES: ********************

const int WIDTH = 255, HEIGHT = 255;    // WIDTH AND HEIGHT RESOLUTION
const int RADIUS = 100;                 // RADIUS OF CIRCLE

const int CENTER_X = 0.5 * WIDTH;       // CENTER X-COORDINATES
const int CENTER_Y = 0.5 * HEIGHT;      // CENTER Y-COORDINATES

int r, g, b;                            // RED, GREEN AND BLUE

//******************** MAIN FUNCTION: ********************

int main() {

  system("open circle.ppm");            // OPENS THE IMAGE
  system("killall ToyViewer");          // CLOSES THE IMAGE

//******************** PPM SETUP: ********************

  ofstream img ("circle.ppm");          // MAKE THE FILE
  img << "P3" << endl;                  // MAGIC NUMBER
  img << WIDTH << endl;                 // WIDTH RESOLUTION
  img << HEIGHT << endl;                // HEIGHT RESOLUTION
  img << "255" << endl;                 // 0-255 MAX RGB VALUE

//******************** FOR EACH PIXEL: ********************

  for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {

      for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {

          if (isInsideCircle(x, y)) {

              r = 50 + Brightness(x, y) % 255;
              g = 50 + Brightness(x, y) % 255;
              b = 50 + Brightness(x, y) % 255;
          }

          else {

              r = 0;
              g = 0;
              b = 0;

          }

          img << r << " " << g << " " << b << endl;
      }
  }

//******************** PROGRAM END: ********************

  system("open circle.ppm"); 
  return 0;

}

//******************** FUNCTIONS: ********************

bool isInsideCircle(int x, int y) {

  if (pow((x - CENTER_X),2) + pow((y - CENTER_Y),2) < pow(RADIUS,2)) {

      return true;

  } else {

      return false;
  }
}

int Brightness(int x, int y) {

  return abs( sqrt( pow((x - CENTER_X),2) + pow((y - CENTER_Y),2)) - RADIUS);

}
```

Comment: The jaddy edges are expected, as you are applying a binary mask to your computed image: points are in = 1, points are out = 0. The problem is that points on the edges of the circle are neither fully in nor fully out: they're on the edge. I've re-tagged your image as `image-processing` so that you may get answers from IP developpers.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel points out, you have a sharp drop. Not actually from 1 to 0, but from {50,50,50} to {0,0,0}. That's because of the `50 + Brightness` lines.

The easy solution is to use a *slightly* less sharp drop. Define a `Brightness2(x,y)` which asymptotically drops from 50 to 0.

```
int Brightness2(int x, int y) {
  int dx = x - CENTER_X;
  int dy = x - CENTER_Y;
  return 50/(1+(dx*dx+dy*dy-RADIUS*RADIUS));
}
```

Comment: That did make it smooth out towards the edge, but didn't really do anything to the pixelated edges. I compared the differences here http://i.imgur.com/tiSjNCj.png

Comment: @MarcusMathiassen: Well, images are still made out of pixels, so that's unavoidable. You can however add increase smoothing by using `100/(2+(...` or `150/(3+(...` etc. This will double or triple the width of the smoothed ring.

Comment: It is worth noting that this method also makes the circle slightly smaller, since the mask is still the same.

Comment: @MarcusMathiassen Slightly increase the radius of your mask, that is, in `isInsideCircle`, replace `pow(RADIUS,2)` with something like: `pow(RADIUS+1,2)`

Comment: @DanielStrul Hmm, that added some weird stuff on the edge, see here http://i.imgur.com/hC7KBAy.png

But i might be doing something wrong. 

Is this how it is supposed to look:
50 + Brightness(x, y) + Brightness2(x, y) % 255; ?

Comment: @MarcusMathiassen No, it looks like it's overshooting :-(

Comment: @DanielStrul I think maybe the best method would be something you mentioned first. Downsampling or something like it.

Comment: @MarcusMathiassen's I'm not sure. There are several bizarre things with your formula `50 + Brightness(x, y) + Brightness2(x, y) % 255`. Try going back to the original definition of of `isInsideCircle`, and multiply rather than adding, e.g.:`50 + Brightness(x, y)/RADIUS * Brightness2(x, y)`

Comment: @JørgenFogh: Actually, it makes it bigger, because this is the formula to use when `! isInsideCircle(x, y)`.

Comment: @MarcusMathiassen: Ah, no, that's entirely not what I intended. I meant `if (isInsideCircle(x, y))  // use 50+ Brightness(x, y) else // use Brightness2(x, y)`.